# Scientific Scale of Y axis with power of ten using matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scale, axis

I want to plot a function but the y-Axis is not in the range as I would like it to have. DO you have a solution for it? I would like to have the y axis in the range of 0 to 1E6 shown with power of ten

```
#packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
# Parameter
#p = np.arange(start=0.0000001, stop=0.0035, step=0.00001)
#Cu = p[1::20]
Cu = np.arange(start=0.0000001, stop=0.0035, step=0.0000001)
n1 = 0.95
n2 = 3.7
n = n1 + n2
Ka1 = 231000
Ka2 = 5900
K = n1*Ka1 + n2*Ka2

# Function r1 and r2
def r_single(cu, n, Ka):
    return (n*Ka*cu)/(1+(Ka*cu))

# Green Curve
def r(cu, n_1, Ka_1, n_2, Ka_2):
    return ((n_1*Ka_1*cu)/(1+(Ka_1*cu)))+((n_2*Ka_2*cu)/(1+(Ka_2*cu)))

g=[n1, Ka1, n2, Ka2]
y = np.empty(len(Cu))
for i in range(len(Cu)):
    y[i] = r(Cu[i], g[0], g[1], g[2], g[3])





#======================================================================
```

this above is just to generate the values needed

```
# Function rose (r = bindungsstellen = bin)
def rose_fun(cu, ni, Ka, bin):
    return (ni*Ka-Ka*bin)

def rose_fun2(cu, ni, Ka, bin):
    return (bin/cu)

rose_var=[y, Cu, n, K]
rose= np.empty(len(Cu))
rose_value = rose_fun(Cu, n, K, y)

plt.plot(Cu, rose_value, color="k")

plt.ticklabel_format(axis = 'y', style = 'scientific')


x3 = plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I read you right, you can use `matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format`. The documentation is available [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html).

For example:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(axis = 'y', style = 'plain')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It partly solved my problem. BUT

Comment: can I force the y-axsis to be shown with powers of ten?

Comment: You can use `scientific` style in `ticklabel_format` or write code like this: `plt.yticks(ticks = np.arange(0, 1200000, 200000), labels = ['0', '2e5', '4e5', '6e5', '8e5', '10e5'])`.